# encoding / can't see letters

Tags: python, encoding, letter

I'm opening links from array and scraping data from them which I put into array and then convert it into csv file. When i open that finished csv file in PyCharm IDE i see my language letters such as ą,ę,ė,į,š,ų,ū correctly but when i open that csv file from desktop my text is corrupted like this "< GrÄ¯Å¾ti atgal". I tried saving csv file with encoding UTF-8 but it didn't help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

with open('neduplikuotas.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data1 = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

data = [''.join(ele) for ele in data1]
i = 1
test = data[3550:]

array = []

for element in test:

    array.append(i)

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(element)
    htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for paragraph in htmlParse.find_all("p"):
        array.append(paragraph.get_text())

    i=i+1

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df.to_csv('viskas5.csv')
```

Comment: Python 3 strings are already Unicode. `to_csv` uses UTF8 in Python 3 by default.  This page is Unicode, specifically UTF8 and obviously the non-US letters appear fine. What application are you using to open that file? When an application has no idea what encoding was used to generate a file it will use the machine's/user's locale and use the encoding specified there. This can be a problem in all operating systems

Comment: Are you using Excel perhaps? In that case you can change the encoding to `utf_8_sig`. This writes a [Byte Order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file that identifies what Unicode encoding is used in the file. Excel at least will respect the BOM and load the file accordingly. Without a BOM, applications can only make guesses, by inspecting the entire file and using heuristics to guess the encoding (eg looking for bytes that would be invalid in UTF8)